# Rails multiple instance of same Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So I am very new to rail but I feel like I ran through a lot documentations.

I am trying to populate my page with two list of @tasks, one with done, and another todo.

how can I get both on one page?

Do I need to do two `.find` and make two active records?

Or is the a way to get it done in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, specify scopes in your model. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :done, -> { where(finished: true) }
  scope :todo, -> { where(finished: false) }
end
```

Then select them in controller:

```
def index
  @done = Task.done
  @todo = Task.todo
end
```

Then show it in a view:

```
<h1>Done tasks</h1>
<% @done.each do |task| %>
  <h5><%= task.title %></h5>
  <p><%= task.created_at %></p>
<% end %>

<h1>Todo tasks</h1>
<% @todo.each do |task| %>
  <h5><%= task.title %></h5>
  <p><%= task.created_at %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Also, method .find designed to select only one entity. Use .where to select several. You can pass multiple params. For example: Task.where(finished: true, 'created_at > ?', Date.today). This will return all finished task created today. As you can see, second param is direct SQL. .where very flexible method.